# Prompt Design HeroCard

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

My bot in webchat is designed to have a purple background and a white text.

[image]

Then I have this code snippet

```
return await step.prompt(CHOOSE_DOCUMENT_TYPE, {
            prompt: 'Please choose the valid government photo ID that you will submit',
            choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(['Driver\'s License', 'Voter\'s ID', 'PRC ID', 'UMID', 'SSS ID', 'GSIS ID']),
            style: ListStyle.heroCard
        });
```

which results to this:

[image]

**Question**: Is there any way I could make the string *"Please choose the valid government photo ID that you will submit"* to be white also?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:I checked this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config) and upon checking my the prompt using inspect element shown in image below:

[image]

The string *"Please choose the valid government photo ID that you will submit"* belongs to "ac-textBlock" this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/net-html/native-styling) suggests that I should configure [Textblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config#schema-textblockconfig) and I what I did is

```
"textBlock" : {
        "size" : "default",
        "weight" : "Bolder",
        "color" : "#FFFFFF",
        "isSubtle": false,
        "wrap": true

    }
```

And I'm not actually sure about that because I can't find from [list of examples](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/master/samples/HostConfig) that uses TextBlockConfig (and yep, that code doesn't work). But this ContainerStylesConfig worked as I successfully changed the background of prompt from white to purple using the code below:

```
"containerStyles": {
        "default": {
            "foregroundColors": {
                "default": {
                    "default": "#FFFFFF",
                    "subtle": "#FFFFFF",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "dark": {
                    "default": "#000000",
                    "subtle": "#66000000",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "light": {
                    "default": "#FFFFFF",
                    "subtle": "#33000000",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "accent": {
                    "default": "#0063B1",
                    "subtle": "#0063B1",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "good": {
                    "default": "#54a254",
                    "subtle": "#DD54a254",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "warning": {
                    "default": "#c3ab23",
                    "subtle": "#DDc3ab23",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "attention": {
                    "default": "#FF0000",
                    "subtle": "#DDFF0000",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                }
            },
            "backgroundColor": "#542781"
        }
    }
```

Now, the prompt looks like this:

[image]

Still black, and all I wanted was to make the string white.

Here is my full code for adaptiveCardHostConfig:

```
const adaptiveCardHostConfig = {
    "hostCapabilities": {
        "capabilities": null
    },
    "choiceSetInputValueSeparator": ",",
    "supportsInteractivity": true,
    "fontTypes": {
        "default": {
            "fontFamily": "Calibri, sans-serif",
            "fontSizes": {
                "small": 12,
                "default": 14,
                "medium": 17,
                "large": 21,
                "extraLarge": 26
            },
            "fontWeights": {
                "lighter": 200,
                "default": 400,
                "bolder": 600
            }
        },
        "monospace": {
            "fontFamily": "'Courier New', Courier, monospace",
            "fontSizes": {
                "small": 12,
                "default": 14,
                "medium": 17,
                "large": 21,
                "extraLarge": 26
            },
            "fontWeights": {
                "lighter": 200,
                "default": 400,
                "bolder": 600
            }
        }
    },
    "spacing": {
        "small": 3,
        "default": 8,
        "medium": 20,
        "large": 30,
        "extraLarge": 40,
        "padding": 10
    },
    "separator": {
        "lineThickness": 1,
        "lineColor": "#EEEEEE"
    },
    "imageSizes": {
        "small": 40,
        "medium": 80,
        "large": 160
    },
    "containerStyles": {
        "default": {
            "foregroundColors": {
                "default": {
                    "default": "#FFFFFF",
                    "subtle": "#FFFFFF",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "dark": {
                    "default": "#000000",
                    "subtle": "#66000000",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "light": {
                    "default": "#FFFFFF",
                    "subtle": "#33000000",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "accent": {
                    "default": "#0063B1",
                    "subtle": "#0063B1",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "good": {
                    "default": "#54a254",
                    "subtle": "#DD54a254",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "warning": {
                    "default": "#c3ab23",
                    "subtle": "#DDc3ab23",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                },
                "attention": {
                    "default": "#FF0000",
                    "subtle": "#DDFF0000",
                    "highlightColors": {
                        "default": "#22000000",
                        "subtle": "#11000000"
                    }
                }
            },
            "backgroundColor": "#542781"
        }
    },
    "actions": {
        "maxActions": 100,
        "spacing": "Default",
        "buttonSpacing": 8,
        "showCard": {
            "actionMode": "Inline",
            "inlineTopMargin": 8,
            "style": "emphasis"
        },
        "preExpandSingleShowCardAction": false,
        "actionsOrientation": "vertical",
        "actionAlignment": "Stretch",
        "wrap": true
    },
    "adaptiveCard": {
        "allowCustomStyle": true
    },
    "imageSet": {
        "maxImageHeight": 100
    },
    "media": {
        "allowInlinePlayback": true
    },
    "factSet": {
        "title": {
            "size": "Default",
            "color": "#FFFFFF",
            "isSubtle": false,
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "wrap": true
        },
        "value": {
            "size": "Default",
            "color": "#FFFFFF",
            "isSubtle": false,
            "weight": "Default",
            "wrap": true
        },
        "spacing": 8
    },
    "textBlock" : {
        "size" : "default",
        "weight" : "Bolder",
        "color" : "#FFFFFF",
        "isSubtle": false,
        "wrap": true

    }
};
```

Did I miss something? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom adaptiveCardHostConfig and send that when you create your webchat session. See [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2034) for an example. I'm not 100% sure but I think the factSet title and/or value color settings will do the trick for you.

You need to pass in adaptiveCardHostConfig as the argument (not sure if it matters but I pass it as the first argument) in your `window.WebChat.renderWebChat` statement.

Comment: hello @billoverton , kindly see my **UPDATE** in the post above. I tried to set "factSet" title.color and value.color to #FFFFFF (or white) but still didn't work. Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: Did you update to pass the adaptiveCardHostConfig with your renderWebChat statement?

Comment: Yes sir, I add adaptiveCardHostConfig to renderWebChat.